# What is the Java grammar that allows "new int[] {0}[0] = 1;" to compile?

Tags: java, language-lawyer, grammar

I am using [The Java® Language Specification Java SE 8 Edition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) as a reference.

Example class:

```
class MyClass {

  void method() {
    new int[] {0}[0] = 1;
  }

}
```

The code `new int[] {0}[0] = 1` should be an [Assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Assignment), as index `0` of the created array is being assigned the value `1`.

An Assignment is comprised of a [LeftHandSide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LeftHandSide), AssignmentOperator, and an Expression. In this example, the LeftHandSide should be `new int[] {0}[0]`.

A LeftHandSide is either an ExpressionName, FieldAccess, or [ArrayAccess](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ArrayAccess). In this example, the LeftHandSide should be an ArrayAccess.

The problem lies with ArrayAccess. ArrayAccess is defined as being either an ExpressionName (not the case for this example) or a PrimaryNoNewArray, and then an Expression between brackets.

The code `new int[] {0}` is an [ArrayCreationExpression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ArrayCreationExpression). A [Primary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Primary) expression is either an ArrayCreationExpression or a PrimaryNoNewArray. So to me, it seems like the second case for ArrayAccess should be Primary and not PrimaryNoNewArray.

I know the JLS doesn't have explicit grammar for everything, such as parenthesized Expressions or parenthesized LeftHandSides, but this seems to be an error. I checked the most recent spec (Java SE 17) and the grammar for ArrayAccess is unchanged.

Comment: Kind of pedantic but an interesting observation none-the-less. Personally, I think it should be a compile error since, as far as I can see, the code is useless because the created array is unreachable. It's only potential effect is just a side-effect on memory, if the compiler doesn't torch it that is.

Comment: @xtratic You could also use it in a while loop condition, but that is equally useless.


`while ((new int[] {0}[0] = 1) > 0) { /* Do stuff */}`

Comment: @xtratic Strictly speaking it's not *useless*, since it allows expressions to be sequenced like statements for their side-effects in a context where a single expression is required, e.g. `new int[] {x += 5, y -= 5, y /= x, x *= y}[3]`. This is obviously a bad use, but it is technically a use.

Comment: @Geoff Yeah, you could use it (`new int[] {0}[0] = 1`) anywhere you can use the result of the expression (in this case `1`) which is definitely still useless because you could still use just the right side expression of the assignment operation anyway. Your example is basically the same as `while (1 > 0) { /* Do stuff */}` aside from the potential (unreachable) memory side-effects.

Comment: @kaya3 I was specifically talking about the assignment to the new array being useless, since no matter what you do the array would become unreachable. `new int[] {x += 5, ... }[3] = x + 1` Of course any expressions you throw in there will have their effects, but the assignment to the array doesn't really have a use unless you consider it as just one extra spot for an expression. I could see potential uses for your example though so long as you actually store a reference to the array Eg. `int[] incremented= new int[] {x++, y++}`

Comment: You wrote “*I know the JLS doesn't have explicit grammar for everything, such as parenthesized Expressions or parenthesized LeftHandSides*”, but actually, parenthesized Expressions are listed in [JLS &15.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8) as *PrimaryNoNewArray*, which leads to the conclusion that the fact that `javac` allows, e.g. `(x) = 4;` is another blatant violation of the specification.

Comment: @Holger not sure how I overlooked parenthesized expressions not being included, as it is definitely there. I must have seen the dedicated [parenthesized expression section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5), saw that there wasn't a specific production named ParenthesizedExpression, and concluded that they didn't have grammar associated with them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like strictly speaking, this doesn't conform with the grammar as specified. But at least, it does make sense for a compiler to allow it: the reason `PrimaryNoNewArray` is used instead of `Primary` here is so that an expression like `new int[1][0]` cannot be ambiguously parsed as either a 2D array or as an array access like `(new int[1])[0]`. If the array has an initializer like `new int[]{0}[0]` then the syntax is not ambiguous because this cannot be parsed as creating a 2D array.

That said, since the JLS doesn't specify that it's allowed, it could be treated as either an implementation detail or a bug in the compiler which allows it.

Comment: If ArrayCreationExpression were split into two different productions (one with the two cases that contain an ArrayInitializer and one with the two cases that do not) could ArrayAccess be updated to include ExpressionName, PrimaryNoNewArray, and ArrayCreationExpressionWithInitializer without introducing any ambiguity?

Comment: @Geoff Yes, that wouldn't create any ambiguity as far as I can tell.